# how to reorder a list using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

when i delete a block div in run time using jquery. i want to reorder the sno.

```
var ID = 0;
$('div.block').each(function() {
    ID++;
    alert(ID)
    $(this+'> table > tbody > tr > td > .sno').html(ID);
});


<div class="block">
   <table>
     <tr><td><span class="sno">1</span></td></tr> 
   </table>
</div>
<div class="block">
   <table>
     <tr><td><span class="sno">2</span></td></tr> 
   </table>
</div>....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after deleting, use this:

```
 $('div.block').each(function(index) {
    alert(index+1)
    $(this).find('.sno').html(index+1);
});
```

Comment: Since index starts from 0, I think it should be index+1.